# When fetching a URL body i get a Forbidden Request Error. How to fix this?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to fetch the given URL,body of the request is only HTML content. I am not able to see the actually json content in the link.I get an error of forbidden Request 403.How to rectify this error. Please someone help me.

```
const request = require ('request');
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
var stockedsnack = [ ];
request({
  url: 'https://ca.desknibbles.com/products.json?limit=250',
  json:true,
  },(error,response,body) => {
    var stockedsnack = body
    console.log(body);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the user agent:

```
request({
  url: 'https://ca.desknibbles.com/products.json?limit=250',
  json:true,
  headers: {'user-agent': 'node'}
  },(error,response,body) => {
    var stockedsnack = body
    console.log(body);
 });
```

[ https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers ]

Comment: You should click to accept this answer because it solved your problem